# redirect user based on Roles?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

Hi I have problem on setting up the admin Module for Web app

1. I had two roles on my System Admin and Tech
2. If the go to admin module the system will see if he is admin or not
3. If the user is not admin will be redirect him to page

   > Sorry, you don t have access to this page !

I used Web.config to restrict access for sub directory Admin

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="admin" />
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

also I have C# code to check if the logged in user is admin or other

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (Page.User.IsInRole("admin"))
            {
                if (!Page.IsPostBack)
                {
                    DisplayRolesInGrid();
                }
            }
            if(!Page.User.IsInRole("admin"))
            {
                Response.Redirect("/accessPage.aspx");
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Seconded - what's the question here? What's the expected behaviour, and what are you seeing instead?

Comment: check for the case first. i mean "admin" or "Admin". If there is no problem with case. Then Some admin Module expert may help.

Did you check if you are getting in from if(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not confuse these two types of role management with each other. They are exclusive of each other.One in web.config and the other is in code via C#. Simply remove the web.config access part and use codein Page_Load function as you have done already.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        if (Page.User.IsInRole("admin"))
        {
            // all is good, do not do anything
            // if you want to initialized something, do it here
        }
        else
        {
            // opps you do not have access here, take him somewhere else
            Response.Redirect("/accessPage.aspx");
        }


}
```

Comment: Is it really better practice to prefer the code model over the web.config one? That means he has to add similar code to every page, where the config model is simpler and can cover an entire directory with a single config line?

Comment: yes, you have to add this code to every page which needs access. It depends on design. Web.conf part is more powerful and more complicated also. Code is simple and it works :)

Comment: I think the web.config will work if he removes <deny users="*"/> - but each to their own :)  You are right about not using both, however: it won't actually break anything, but it doesn't help either.

Comment: thank for information I was very confuse between using Web.config or the code behind

Answer (score 0):

No idea what your question is, but I can see at least one problem:
    `<deny users="*"/>` means deny everyone. Should be `<deny users="?" />` to keep out the unauthenticated, and then `<deny roles="Tech" />` to make sure your tech users aren't permitted.